# Syntax highlight in vim not working at all

Tags: vim

I've just been busy configuring vim to look like an IDE with the help of [this](https://github.com/jez/vim-as-an-ide) and [this](https://coderoncode.com/tools/2017/04/16/vim-the-perfect-ide.html) source, but i can't seem to get the syntax highlighting to work.

In my `~/.vimrc` i have the following two settings `filetype plugin indent on` and `syntax on` that supposed to highlight the syntax, but whenever i open a file (Javascript for example) it doesn't work.

When i open the file and do `:syntax list` i get the following response: `No syntax items defined for this buffer`

I (quick) search on the internet al refer to the settings i mentioned (and are defined correctly).

What am i missing?

Below my whole `.vimrc` content

```
set nocompatible

"""" Config Vundle plugin manager """""
filetype off

set rtp=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

"""" Plugins """"
Plugin 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'
Plugin 'tomasr/molokai'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plugin 'jistr/vim-nerdtree-tabs'
Plugin 'vim-syntastic/syntastic'
Plugin 'xolox/vim-misc'
Plugin 'xolox/vim-easytags'
Plugin 'majutsushi/tagbar'
Plugin 'ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim'
Plugin 'vim-scripts/a.vim'
Plugin 'airblade/vim-gitgutter'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plugin 'Raimondi/delimitMate'
Plugin 'jez/vim-superman'
Plugin 'christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator'
Plugin 'jez/vim-c0'
Plugin 'jez/vim-ispc'
Plugin 'kchmck/vim-coffee-script'
Plugin 'godlygeek/tabular'
Plugin 'HTML-AutoCloseTag'
Plugin 'ekalinin/Dockerfile.vim'
Plugin 'cakebaker/scss-syntax.vim'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-surround'
Plugin 'ntpeters/vim-better-whitespace'
Plugin 'edkolev/tmuxline.vim'

"""" OSX stupid backspace fix """"
set backspace=indent,eol,start

call vundle#end()
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on

"""" General settings """"
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set ruler
set number
set showcmd
set incsearch
set hlsearch

"""" Set tabs """"
set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set smarttab
set expandtab

"""" Enable mouse support """"
set mouse=a

"""" Enable highlighting of the current line """"
set cursorline

"""" Support symbols in the title bar """"
hi clear SignColumn

"""" Colorscheme (Solarized) """"
set background=dark
colorscheme solarized

" Always show statusbar
set laststatus=2

"""" Enable Menlo font """"
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1

" Show PASTE if in paste mode
let g:airline_detect_paste=1

" Show airline for tabs too
let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled = 1

" Use the solarized theme for the Airline status bar
let g:airline_theme='solarized'

"""" Nerdtree config """"
" Open/close NERDTree Tabs with \t
nmap <silent> <leader>t :NERDTreeTabsToggle<CR>
" To have NERDTree always open on startup
let g:nerdtree_tabs_open_on_console_startup = 1

"""" Scrooloose/syntastic settings """"
let g:syntastic_error_symbol = '✘'
let g:syntastic_warning_symbol = "▲"
augroup mySyntastic
  au!
  au FileType tex let b:syntastic_mode = "passive"
augroup END

"""" Easytags settings """
set tags=./tags;,~/.vimtags
" Sensible defaults
let g:easytags_events = ['BufReadPost', 'BufWritePost']
let g:easytags_async = 1
let g:easytags_dynamic_files = 2
let g:easytags_resolve_links = 1
let g:easytags_suppress_ctags_warning = 1

"""" Tagbar settings """"
" Open/close tagbar with \b
nmap <silent> <leader>b :TagbarToggle<CR>
" Open tagbar automatically whenever possible
autocmd BufEnter * nested :call tagbar#autoopen(0)

"""" Vimgutter settings """
" In vim-airline, only display "hunks" if the diff is non-zero
let g:airline#extensions#hunks#non_zero_only = 1

"""" delimitMate settings """
let delimitMate_expand_cr = 1
augroup mydelimitMate
  au!
  au FileType markdown let b:delimitMate_nesting_quotes = ["`"]
  au FileType tex let b:delimitMate_quotes = ""
  au FileType tex let b:delimitMate_matchpairs = "(:),[:],{:},`:'"
  au FileType python let b:delimitMate_nesting_quotes = ['"', "'"]
augroup END

"""" Superman config """"
noremap K :SuperMan <cword><CR>
```

**EDIT:**

Below the response of `vim --version`

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Nov 29 2017 18:37:46)
Included patches: 1-503, 505-680, 682-1283
Compiled by root@apple.com
Normal version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +file_in_path    -mouse_sgr       +tag_old_static
-arabic          +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  -tag_any_white
+autocmd         +float           -mouse_urxvt     -tcl
-balloon_eval    +folding         +mouse_xterm     -termguicolors
-browse          -footer          +multi_byte      -terminal
+builtin_terms   +fork()          +multi_lang      +terminfo
+byte_offset     -gettext         -mzscheme        +termresponse
+channel         -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +textobjects
+cindent         +iconv           +num64           +timers
-clientserver    +insert_expand   +packages        +title
-clipboard       +job             +path_extra      -toolbar
+cmdline_compl   +jumplist        -perl            +user_commands
+cmdline_hist    -keymap          +persistent_undo +vertsplit
+cmdline_info    +lambda          +postscript      +virtualedit
+comments        -langmap         +printer         +visual
-conceal         +libcall         -profile         +visualextra
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python/dyn      +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +vreplace
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
+dialog_con      -lua             -rightleft       +windows
+diff            +menu            +ruby/dyn        +writebackup
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -X11
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xim
-emacs_tags      -mouseshape      +startuptime     -xpm
+eval            -mouse_dec       +statusline      -xsmp
+ex_extra        -mouse_gpm       -sun_workshop    -xterm_clipboard
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   +syntax          -xterm_save
-farsi           -mouse_netterm   +tag_binary
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DMACOS_X_UNIX  -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: gcc   -L/usr/local/lib -o vim        -lm -lncurses  -liconv -framework Cocoa
```

**EDIT 2**

I now noticed that when i try to reload my `.vimrc` file, i get the following error:

```
Error detected while processing /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syntax.vim:
line   42:
E216: No such group or event: filetypedetect BufRead
```

Which [points](http://wiki.kartbuilding.net/index.php/Syntax_Highlighting_Problems_with_vim) me in the [direction](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=168167) of changing my `runtimepath` value, but i don't have that defined anywhere. I've tried adding it to my `.vimrc`, but i still get the same error after reloading.

I've placed it at the top of the document (right after `set nocompatible`, so perhaps the position could be the issue, but if so, where should i place it then?

Comment: Show us the complete output of `$ vim --version`.

Comment: @romainl i've added the response to the question

Comment: `filetype off`...

Comment: @lcd047 I noticed, but since i'm new to vim i closely followed the first repository i mentioned and they are also [double defining it](https://github.com/jez/vim-as-an-ide/commit/dcc0c8d). I tried removing the top one, but without any result. I did however get an error message which i included in my initial question

Comment: Is there a reason your MacOS backspace fix is within your Vundle call?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons No, i moved it outside the Vundle call, but with no result

Comment: My bet is that the javascript file is not automatically detected as such.

`set ft?` should print javascript.

Comment: have you tried switching syntax on to syntax enable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Damnit, i was missing a `+` character in line 6

set `set rtp=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim` should have been `set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim`. Now it works!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you can `:source ~/.vimrc` successfully with no error when you edit update `~/.vimrc`.

Step to do source vimrc:

1. `vim ~/.vimrc`
2. type `:source ~/.vimrc`
3. enter